# Passport.use will not take an instance of passport-saml.Strategy

Tags: node.js, typescript, passport.js, passport-saml

I am using two libraries to implement auth. Passport.js and passport-saml (which is just a strategy implementation for passport.js). After creating the passport-saml strategy the passport.use function should accept that strategy and use it for auth. instead typescript fails to compile and I get this error:

Argument of type 'import("/home/patrick/Workspace/School/SP/makerspace/server/node_modules/passport-saml/lib/passport-saml/strategy").Strategy' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("/home/patrick/Workspace/School/SP/makerspace/server/node_modules/@types/passport/index").Strategy'.
Types of property 'authenticate' are incompatible.
Type '(req: RequestWithUser, options: AuthenticateOptions) => void' is not assignable to type '(this: StrategyCreated<Strategy, Strategy & StrategyCreatedStatic>, req: Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>, options?: any) => any'.
Types of parameters 'req' and 'req' are incompatible.
Property 'samlLogoutRequest' is missing in type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>' but required in type 'RequestWithUser'

not sure what to do...

[screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epAqg.png)

Comment: There is a bug report for this in github:  https://github.com/node-saml/passport-saml/issues/549